# Generating a random key with ascii letters, numbers, and special characters in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a brute force attack on a decoder. I want to generate as many different keys until I find the secret key. I know the key should be of length 2 symbols. I know theres a string.ascii_letters call and a string.digits call. Is there a way to include special characters like !@#$ and etc to generate keys?

Comment: Post the code that you've tried. What's the problem with `string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$'`?

Comment: Sure, there's `string.punctuation`. Also `string.printable` (which includes whitespace chars)

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I needed the other special characters also like &*(=^% and then any others.

Comment: So what's stopping you from concatenating those to the list of characters to choose from?

Comment: Where's the code showing how you're trying to generate keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string.printable`.

The string of characters that are considered printable. This is a combination of **digits, letters, punctuation, and whitespace**.

You can read more in the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.printable

Answer (score 1):

If you need ascii letters digits and special characters you can do next

```
characters = string.ascii_letters  + string.digits + string.punctuation
```

If you also need whitespace symbols than you can simply use
`string.printable` which includes all of above plus whitespace symbols